# How to specify a 10.5 font size when using FontFactory mvc

Tags: model-view-controller

This works:
Font font_medium = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10);

and this does not build:
Font font_medium = FontFactory.GetFont(FontFactory.HELVETICA, 10.5);

I get the build error:

*> Error    3   The best overloaded method

> match for
>   'iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.GetFont(string,
>   string)' has some invalid
>   arguments C:\Documents and
>   Settings\Administrator\Desktop\lms4\LMS\Lms.Web\Controllers\PaymentItemController.cs  24  28  Lms.Web*

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.GetFont does not recognize fractional font sizes. I don't believe there is a work around, the only thing you could try to do is find a Helvetica Wide perhaps to give the illusion of a slightly larger font...